# Could not find Wifi?

Tags: wireless, 19.04

I have recently installed Ubuntu 19.04 in my Lenovo ideapad along with windows 10 .

I could not find how to turn on WiFi.I could not even get anything like " No WiFi adapter found" or something like that.

I do not have any experience of using Linux.

Help me.

**Edit**

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`:

```
Network controller [ 0280 ] : Realtek semiconductor co ., ltd RTL8821CE 802.11ac
PCIe wireless network Adapter [ 10ec : c821 ] 0: ideapad_WLAN: wireless soft blocked : none , hard blocked : none
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Network controller [ 0280 ] : Realtek semiconductor co ., ltd RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe wireless network Adapter [ 10ec : c821 ]                   0: ideapad_WLAN: wireless soft blocked : none , hard blocked : none @pilot6

Answer (score 1):

You can connect the Ethernet and run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This worked for me.